# Vue form input types not being re-rendered on state change and method call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have the following html:

```
<b-row no-gutters v-for="(exp, index) in currentExps" :key="index">
  <Field :id="exp.exp_id" name="Status" type="text" disabled />
  <Field :id="exp.exp_id" name="ELN" type="text" :disabled="submitted(exp)" />
  <Field :id="exp.exp_id" name="Solvent" :type="type(exp)" :disabled="submitted(exp)
</b-row>
```

Each "Field" is a custom component which renders a different type of form input depending on the value of the type prop passed to it. For some of these "Field" components I determine the type and whether the field should be disabled or not through a couple of methods as shown:

```
submitted(exp) {
      return exp.Status === "Submitted";
    },
    type(exp, field) {
      console.log(field);

      if (exp.Status === "Submitted") {
        console.log("it is true");
        return "text";
      } else {
        return "select";
      }
    }
```

When I click a button, exp.Status is converted to "Submitted". When this happens, both methods run - the fields are all converted to being disabled. However, where I then wish "Solvent" to be switched from a select field type to a text field type this does not occur. It is as though the app needs to re-render as via hot-reload the desired changes are observed.

I was wondering if anyone can explain this behaviour? Essentially the disabled state of the fields is updated but the type is not when state is changed.

Thanks

Comment: Since there's no special behavior that would prevent the `type` method from changing the value of the binding, chances are the problem is in the `Field` component, not handling the prop change properly.

Comment: Correct, I had to use a computed property in the child to react to the prop change as opposed to static data